# Hide/show map marker on Here map

Tags: javascript, here-api

```
   const testIcon = `<svg width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect stroke="white" fill="blue" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" /></svg>`;
```

Without using this on CSS, the map marker and just displaying on page, the class gets applied.

```
.hide { visibility: hidden }
.show { visibility: visible }
```

I tried using both H.map.Icon and H.map.DomIcon and respective Marker and DomMarker, with no success.

```
var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(testIcon);
var marker = new H.map.DomMarker({lat: 'latitudeVal', lng: 'longitudeVal'};, { icon:icon })
map.addObject(marker);
```

This is for an existing map. I want to flip the classes (or just set visibility to hidden) on specific markers. I have several map markers on the map. How can I retrieve specific markers and set visibility to hidden or back to visible? 
Is there a Javascript solution possible without re-invoking the API at all?

I have been trying the API approach too, but am not sure how to loop through all the markers and set visibility on specific ones. [DomMarker Get position](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-dommarker.html#h-map-dommarker__getposition), [setting visibility](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-dommarker.html#h-map-dommarker__setvisibility) Is this needed, as this involves additional API calls and performance?

I want to avoid extra calls to the API if it's not needed and just flip the visibility on the marker directly if it's possible at all.

```
// The icon gets added fine... 
  const testIcon = `<svg width="25" height="25" class="show" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><ellipse cx="10" cy="10" rx="8" ry="8" fill="blue"  /></svg>`;

  const hideIcon = `<svg visibility="hidden" width="12" height="12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><ellipse cx="6" cy="6" rx="5" ry="5" fill="#5980B2" stroke="white" /></svg>`;
  let mapMarkerList = [];  // Could this be used. 
    data.forEach(function (mapMarker, i) {
        var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(testIcon);
        let marker = new H.map.DomMarker( { lat: mapMarker.lat, lng: mapMarker.long } , { icon:icon })
        map.addObject(marker);
        mapMarkerList.append(marker); 
   });

    toggleMarkers(data, map, '1'); 

// dataset looks like:
dataset = {
        { lat:'123', long:'-123', customData: 'abc' }, 
        { lat:'123', long:'-123', customData: 'x' }, 
        { lat:'123', long:'-123', customData: 'abc' }, 
    }
        function realToggleMarkers(mapMarkers, valueToFilter, map) {
// Hide all 'abc' lat/long markers... 
        dataset.forEach(function (value, i) {
           if(valueToFilter !== value.customData ) {
              console.log('Hide');
                // There's also a value.lat and value.long here that I create marker with. I need to hide that specific marker.
                // mapMarkers loop through? === value.lat? then hide.
                // mapMarker[0].getPosition().lat // How can I check this matches value.lat without nested loops?
          } else { 
            console.log('Show');
          }
        });
}

    // Doesn't work....
    // Use the map object above and hide/show specific markers.....     
      function toggleMarkers(mapMarkers, map, valueToFilter) {  
        mapMarkers.forEach(function (value, i) {
            if(i%2===0) {
            // How can we get individual marker from the 'map' object built out above?
              console.log(marker.getIcon());
              // Doesn't work.... 
              marker.getIcon().setVisibility(false); // Or any other approach changing the visibility....

            }
    });
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't want to hide the map objects by removing them and then just adding them again when you need to show them?

Comment: Well, I am still learning to use the API and either option works for me.. As long as there are no expensive calls to the api and the page updates fast. There are a lot of repetitive pins and I wouldn't want to delete and add them repetitively. I thought hiding/showing existing elements would be faster vs DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use H.map.object.setVisibility(boolean)

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics_api/h-map-object.html#h-map-object__setvisibility
marker is also H.map.object. It should be below.

```
value.setVisibility(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some copy/paste work here that you did and not modified: `console.log(marker.getIcon());` should this not be `console.log(value.getIcon());`

`marker` is not a variable inside the foreach loop

Comment: thanks for noticing that. I think what I'm trying to do is beyond checking for i%2 ===0.. I actually have the lat/long with me in a list, that I use to create the marker. There's some added information there in that list, that I need to look at before deciding to hide the map.. and for that, I need to see that lat/long value that the marker uses or points to. This is what I try to do while getting the icon. which is probably incorrect...